# SELECT when table names are stored in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table containing two columns, both of which have table names in them.

e.g.:

```
sourceTableName  |  destinationTableName
---------------  |  -------------------
sourceTable1     |  destinationTable1
sourceTable2     |  destinationTable2
sourceTable3     |  destinationTable3
sourceTable4     |  destinationTable4
sourceTable5     |  destinationTable5   ...
```

I want to compare each row in each pair of tables in both directions in order to spot any differences:

e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM sourceTable1
EXCEPT  
SELECT * FROM destinationTable1

SELECT * FROM destinationTable1
EXCEPT  
SELECT * FROM sourceTable1
```

Entering the tables manually isn't really an option, so how can I get the `FROM` bit to look at the rows in my 'table of table names'?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter. Cheers, could you elaborate?

Comment: @BankySQL check out TSQL's `EXEC` and `sp_executesql` commands. They allow you dynamically build SQL statements in a VARCHAR variable to which you can add table names at run time and then execute those statements.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter.  Thanks, that's looking like a promising lead.

Answer (score 0):

As Yuriy stated in the comments of the question, Dynamic SQL is the way to go. This is what I would do (and have done in the past). This should get you started.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ SQL = N''

SELECT
  @SQL = @SQL + N' SELECT * FROM [' + sourceTableName + N'] EXCEPT SELECT * FROM [' + destinationTableName + N'];'
FROM
  tblOfTableNames

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Is there more than one schema?

Comment: This will lead to syntax errors - you need a space before `EXCEPT`. You should also terminate the queries with a semi-colon and, just in case, put square brackets around the table names.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand! I noticed it after I posted the answer. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'SELECT * FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(sourceTableName)
 + ' EXCEPT SELECT * FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(destinationTableName)
 + ';
' FROM dbo.we_have_no_idea_what_your_table_is_called;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```